# Generating organization IP address range data

Tags: http, url, geolocation, ip

I want to get the IP ranges of every college/campus I can.

I found one site which seems to have a pretty reliable and comperhensive file of this sort:
http://www.bluetack.co.uk/config/edu.gz

I was unable to find any information on how they generated that list.

I'm interested in doing this so I can determine a user's school when they come to my website.  It would be optimal if I could generate my own list and know how it's done rather than relying on the (possibly out of date) one from Bluetack.

I'm sure this can be done by hand, school by school by using a whois database, but I'm interested in a programmatic method which would get all of them at once.

**UPDATE**: I just came up with the idea that they might be querying a whois database for all *.edu records.  If there was some way to go about querying all the .edu's relatively quickly that might be the solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an answer to your update but not your original question:

You can query the whois database with the `whois` command. You can use wildcards in your search:

```
whois %.edu
```

This will show you the first 100, because the search is limited to 100 records. You can circumvent this limitation by doing smaller queries: `aa%.edu`, `ab%.edu`, `ac%.edu` and so on. It can be done with two for loops:

```
for A in a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z ; do
    for B in a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z ; do
        whois $A$B%.edu | grep EDU$
    done
done
```

But I can not see how this could help to solve your original question: what you are looking for are all delegations (PTR records) done by a [LIR](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Internet_Registry) to a customer who owns a specific domain. This information might be confidential.

Comment: Gave you bounty..  Any suggestions on getting LIR's?

Answer (score 3):

How about a reverse DNS lookup on the visitor instead of matching to an IP block?
I.e. take the visitor's IP, lookup their hostname, and if it ends in .edu then there's your school.
The DNS system becomes your database.

Comment: The reverse lookup of a visitors IP address does not necessarily result in an .edu name. It is also possible that it results in a carrier name. The referenced data might be outdated but if you take the first address of "STANFORD UNIV MED CTR-040804051842" the reverse lookup is: adsl-64-166-81-185.dsl.sntc01.pacbell.net